# Is there any refresh and occurrence fields like sensu core in sensu go?

Tags: monitoring, sensu

We are using sensu go with email handler. In sensu go, is there any way to use occurrence,refresh like sensu core?

Answer (score 1):

Sensu contributor here

`occurrence` and `refresh` attributes are no longer present/valid in Sensu Go. If you're wanting similar behavior, I suggest looking at the [fatigue check filter](https://bonsai.sensu.io/assets/nixwiz/sensu-go-fatigue-check-filter). You'd end up having a check that looks like:

```
---
type: CheckConfig
api_version: core/v2
metadata:
  name: linux-cpu-check
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    fatigue_check/occurrences: '3'
    fatigue_check/interval: '900'
    fatigue_check/allow_resolution: 'false'
spec:
  command: check-cpu -w 90 c 95
  handlers:
  - email
  interval: 60
  publish: true
  runtime_assets: 
  subscriptions:
  - linux
```

Comment: Not to say that your answer wouldn't be useful, but you do seem to be one of the contributors of that project and you must always disclose your affiliation, as per SO's promotion rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion